# takePicture() landscape mode rotation android

Tags: android

I am taking an image from camera using:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null,
                            new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
```

But the image I am taking is landscape and I want it portrait, I tried converting the file into bitmap, rotate it and then save it again, here is my `onPictureTaken()` function and `rotate()` function inside `PhotoHandler.class`:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("Error", "Can't create directory to save image.");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
    pictureFile = new File(filename);
    st1 = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {
        Log.d("Error", "File" + filename + "not saved: "
                + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    Bitmap b = rotate(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath()),270);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    CameraPreview.safeToTakePicture = true;
    galleryAddPic();
}

public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int degree) {
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.setRotate(degree);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
}
```

Anyway, it takes too long, I tried using `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);` but it changes only the preview of the camera, the picture taken is still the same, I also tried getting the parameters of the camera and changing it like here:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Without success, any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT :**
New code:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    File pictureFileDir = getDir();
    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("Error", "Can't create directory to save image.");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";
    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
    pictureFile = new File(filename);
    st1 = pictureFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Bitmap b = rotate(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length),270);
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    CameraPreview.safeToTakePicture = true;
    galleryAddPic();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyway, it takes too long

Your current algorithm looks like this:

- Start with the photo in memory
- Save the photo to disk, which is slow
- Read the photo back in from disk to memory, which is slow
- Rotate the reloaded photo

A more efficient approach would be:

- Start with the photo in memory
- Rotate the photo

`BitmapFactory` has `decodeByteArray()` to get a `Bitmap` back for rotation purposes.

Comment: @DAVIDBALAS1: If your objective is to save the rotated photo, what you have should be more efficient than what you had before.

Comment: Yes I am trying to save the image. Thanks for helping.